# HP ALM Requirements Target Release field

Tags: hp-alm

Why does the 'Target Release' drop-down in the Requirements details allow a user to select more than one release?

From a business point of view, I want to understand why I would target a requirement to more than one release.  If I've targeted a release, for example, to 2.0, why would I target the release to, for example, 2.1?

On the other hand, if a user can select more than one release, why isn't the field labelled 'Target Releases'?

Comment: We are working in the opposite mindset closer to: Why wouldn't every release have the current active requirements automatically?

For something like regression, the requirements under test become a target for every cycle, right?

Some companies have parallel release schedules and requirements may actually be added to both releases and need to be tested separately possibly.  I think this is more discussionary than an actual answer, so I don't want to answer the question.